# Jquery mobile show/hide div on tap

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile page that contains a button that when tapped should show/hide a div. I seem to be missing something. I've worked through similar questions on SO with no success, can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong?

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="moreFilters" class="moreFilters" data-role="button">View more filters</a>
<div id="filters"> Blah </div>
```

CSS:

```
div#filters {
    display: none;
}
```

JQ:

```
$('#myPage').live('pageinit', function(event) {
    $("#moreFilters").bind('tap',function(event, ui){
        $('#filters').toggle('fast', function() {});
    })
});
```

I've also tried:

```
$('#moreFilters').live('tap',function(event) {
    $("#filters").toggle(); //  toggles the visibility/display of the element.
});
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Bind an [jQuery click event](http://api.jquery.com/click/) for testing

2. Try to set [jQuery css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to display: block instead of .toggle() for testing

3. Show an alert or other output in the second parameter (in the function) of the tap event, then you can see if your event is fired correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you do something like this,

```
<script>
    var isMenuVisible = true

    function showHideMenu() {
        isMenuVisible = !isMenuVisible;
        var menuPrin= document.getElementById("divMenu");

        if(isMenuVisible) {
            menuPrin.style.visibility = "visible";
            menuPrin.style.width = "30%";
        } else {
            menuPrin.style.visibility = "hidden";
            menuPrin.style.width = "0%";
        }
    }
</script>
```

This `script` could you put it at end of your page.

Now, point you `id="divMenu"` to your `div` that want hide, ok, and `onclick="showHideMenu();"` function on element that fire event.

All this simulate it `tap` and `toggle` events.

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - I used this to track down it was actually this toggle() event that was causing the issue I switched to show() and it worked fine.